# NoMethodError in OrdersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I'm building a simple shopping application and trying to use Ryan Bates's "#145 Integrating Active Merchant" for guidance to build the checkout process.

Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :order_products
has_many :products, through: :order_products

attr_accessor :card_number, :security_code, :card_expires_on


def credit_card

    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        :first_name             => first_name,
        :last_name              => last_name,
        :card_number            => card_number,
        :verification_value     => security_code,
        :month                  => card_expires_on{month},
        :year                   => card_expires_on{year}
        )
end


def self.purchase(basket)

    response = GATEWAY.purchase(Product.total_basket_price(basket), credit_card)

end




end
```

Orders_controller:

```
    def create
    
    @order = Order.new

    basket.each do |item_id|
        @order.order_products.build(product: Product.find(item_id))
    end

    if @order.save!
        if @order.purchase
            render "show"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    else
        render "new"
    end

end
```

Product model:

```
  def self.total_basket_price(basket)
    where(id: basket.to_a).sum(:price)*100
  end
```

When i click submit, i receive the following error message:

> NoMethodError in OrdersController#create
>
> undefined method `purchase'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`purchase` is a class record, but you try to call it on the instance of `Order`. Also, this method requires an argument, but you try to call it without them.

Comment: As Marek says it's a class method because of the `self.method_name` so if you want to call it on an instance change it to `def purchase(basket)` though I don't think you'll need to pass in the basket once you've made it an order so just `def purchase`

Comment: @James And, of course, pass basket as an argument. I'd also advice you to do it only if you need any of your `Order` instace attributes in this method. In other case, you should stay with class method and call it with `Order.purchse(your_basket_object)`.

Comment: @Marek, @Baloo Great thanks, so i actually had the way that @Baloo suggested then changed it, changing it back solves that issue however now i have an `undefined method "card_number=" for #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard:0x007faeb80eed68> `

Comment: The railscast you're using is quite old.  [Docs](http://activemerchant.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveMerchant/Billing/CreditCard.html) looks like it's just number rather than card_number now

Comment: @Baloo eye of a hawk! Much appreciated :)